# Closure of this set under addition

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Define $S = \{ (x_n)_n \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \mid \sum\limits_{n=1}^{∞} {x_n}^2 < ∞ \}.$

How do I show that this set is closed under pointwise addition?

Let $(x_n)_n$, $(y_n)_n$ be two sequences with their associated series converging to $L_1 := \sum {x_n}^2$ and $L_2 := \sum {y_n}^2$. How do I show that the series associated to $(x_n + y_n)_n$ converges, too?

So far, I can reason $\sum_n (x_n + y_n)^2 = L_1 + L_2 + 2\sum x_n y_n$, but how do I go from here?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Note that the splitting $\sum (x_n + y_n)^2 = L_1 + L_2 + 2\sum x_n y_n$ requires the assumption of $\sum x_n y_n$ to converge. For the same reason why $\lim a_n + b_n = \lim a_n + \lim b_n$ requires both limits on the RHS to exist. The answers post-rationalize the splitting, so it's fine after all -- just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{n}|x_n||y_n|\leq \sqrt{\sum_{n}x_n^2}\sqrt{\sum_{n}y_n^2}.$$

Comment: Oh! Because $|x_n| ≥ x_n$ so $\sum |x_n| ≥ \sum x_n$ right?

Comment: Oh my bad, I was commenting under the other answer, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Given what you have done, what is left to prove is that $\sum {x_n y_n}$
is convergent. To do so, you need some form of Cauchy Swartz inequality and state the following:
$$|x_n y_n|=\sqrt{x_n^2 \cdot y_n^2}\leq \frac{x_n^2 + y_n^2}{2}$$
This inequality is sometimes called AM-GM and, we can deduce from it that the sum $\sum {|x_n y_n|}$ is convergent.
Thus the dum in question is absolutely convergent.

Comment: So $\sum (x_n + y_n)^2 = L_1 + L_2 + 2 \sum x_n y_n ≤ L_1 +L_2 + 2 \sum |x_n y_n| = L_1 + L_2 + 2 \sum \sqrt{{x_n}^2 {y_n}^2} ≤ L_1 + L_2 + \sum ({x_n}^2 + {y_n}^2) = 2L_1 + 2L_2 < ∞$, correct?

Comment: @William You can even make it shorter. Since $\sum |x_n y_n|$ converges as per the answer, so does $\sum x_n y_n =: C$ (abs. convergence implies convergence w/o abs. value). Hence $\sum (x_n+y_n)^2 = L_1 + L_2 + C < \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to use the fact that $(a+b)^{2}\leq 2(a^{2}+b^{2})$ so $\sum (x_n+y_n)^{2} \leq 2\sum x_n^{2}+2\sum y_n^{2} <\infty$. This avoids C-S inequality.